# How to use version odfdom-java 0.10.0?

Tags: java, libreoffice, odt, odf, odftoolkit

I've been studying ODF Toolkit to generate .odt files. This example [Creating Text Documents Using ODFDOM](http://www.langintro.com/odfdom_tutorials/create_odt.html) runs when I use 0.8.6 version, but fails when I change to the newer version 0.10.0 (or even the 0.9.0).

Does anybody there know a site or another source of information on how to migrate the source code from version 0.8.6 to 0.10.0? Things that don't work anymore in that source code in [1](http://www.langintro.com/odfdom_tutorials/create_odt.html): [source code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hAUkm.png)

Thank you.